# Splitting string with random white spaces

Tags: javascript

I want to split a string like

```
"John   john@gmail.com     +3091424213                Hawai"
```

with text.split(" ") but it splitting the first space only. I've tried put + text.split(" +"), but i get

```
John  john@gmail.com       +3091424213             Hawai   
undefined 
undefined 
undefined
```

same with text.split("\s+"), the output is the same.

My code

```
  var splitText = text.split(" +");
  console.log(splitText[0]);
  console.log(splitText[1]);
  console.log(splitText[2]);
  console.log(splitText[3]);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `String#split` takes a regular expression or a string, so when you want to pass it a regular expression it has to be as a regex object. Does `text.split(/ +/)` work?

Comment: Oh..sorry, my mistake i put string quote. It is working @Ryan, but does not accept newline paragraph, if i put \n it does not recognize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var string = "John   john@gmail.com     +3091424213                Hawai";
string.split(/\s* \s*/);
```

Comment: `/\s+/` is somewhat shorter. ;-)

Comment: OK. it is working now even i put newline pargraph. Thanks both of you.